# sort a txt file, find duplicates, but also print the lines they were found in

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Given a txt file, that has the following values:

```
123 
123 
234 
234 
123 
345
```

I use

```
sort FILE | uniq -cd
```

in order to get the number of counts each value is found.
But how I could output also the row it was found?

Output:

```
123  3 0;1;4
234  2 2;3
```

The row count is zero based, thus the above numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
{
  frequency[$1]++
  if (line[$1]=="")
  {
    line[$1]=NR-1
  }
  else
  {
    line[$1]=line[$1]";"NR-1
  }
}
END{
  for (j in frequency)
    if (frequency[j]>1)
      print j, frequency[j], line[j]
}' file
```

> `$1`: content of first column
>
> `NR`: current line number

Output:

```
234 2 2;3
123 3 0;1;4
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1]";":"")(NR-1); cnt[$1]++ }
     END{ for(i in a) if(a[i]~/;/) { print i,cnt[i],a[i] } }' file
```

- `a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1]";":"")(NR-1)` - accumulating row numbers (starting from `0`) for each grouped value `$1` via concatenating multiple occurrences with `;`
- `cnt[$1]++` - count numbers of value occurrences

---

The output:

```
123 3 0;1;4
234 2 2;3
```

Comment: Awk is so powerful but it is cryptic like perl - I have a hard time understanding my own scripts after a few weeks.

Comment: i have run the above, and it outputs also the unique values, and i found out that the above also has a +1 result: 123 4 and 234 3

Comment: @hedibisuv, sounds unreal - check your code for manual errors and make sure that you have posted the actual input content

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is tagged awk/sed, but for the sake of comparison Look how much verbose is the Python version:

```
import sys

dictionary = {}
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    dictionary.setdefault(line.strip(), []).append(str(i))

for value, lines_numbers in dictionary.items():
    print(value, len(line_numbers), ";".join(line_numbers))
```

Testing:

```
$ python script.py < FILE
123 3 0;1;4
234 2 2;3
345 1 5
```

Comment: interesting solution, seems in my raw data, i have unicode characters which the above gives me errrors...

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: ~$ python script.py < dups.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 2349: invalid continuation byte